# Taskqueue set exact/approximate excution time

Tags: python, google-app-engine, batch-processing, task-queue

Is it possible to set exact or at least approximate execution time of scheduled task on GAE that will execute at rate specified (5/s, 100/h)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want something to happen regularly at a particular time, then you should use [cron](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html). Create a handler that will spawn Tasks and have cron trigger it at a certain time.

If you need to do this programatically (ie, it's not regular enough to use cron) then you can set a `countdown` on a Taskqueue Task when it's created to delay when the task runs.

> [countdown is] Number of seconds into the future that this Task should execute, measured from time of insertion. Currently defaults to zero.

See [Task](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html)

So say you wanted to execute your task at 5pm today you could calculate the rough time til you want your task to execute in seconds, then add a task to the queue:

```
seconds_til_start = (datetime(2011,3,22,17,00) - datetime.now()).seconds
taskqueue.add(url='/yourtask', countdown=seconds_til_start)
```

Comment: awesome, I've missed countdown property. that was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Bojan Also note the 'eta' task, which specifies an absolute, rather than relative, time. Bear in mind that these are earliest execution times - your task will execute at or after the specified time.

Comment: Is the countdown feature only available on push queues? Or pull as well?